# Runtimeerror: Cuda out of memory - problem in code or gpu?

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, cuda, gpu

I am currently working on a computer vision project. I keep getting a runtime error that says "CUDA out of memory". I have tried all possible ways like reducing batch size and image resolution, clearing the cache, deleting variables after training starts, reducing image data and so on... Unfortunately, this error doesn't stop. I have a Nvidia Geforce 940MX graphics card on my HP Pavilion laptop. I have installed cuda 10.2 and cudNN from the pytorch installation page. My aim was to create a flask website out of this model but I am stuck with this issue. Any suggestions to this problem will be helpful.

This is my code

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import os
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import albumentations as A
from torch.utils.data import TensorDataset, DataLoader,Dataset
from torchvision import models
from collections import defaultdict
from torch.utils.data.sampler import RandomSampler
import torch.optim as optim
from torch.optim import lr_scheduler
from sklearn import model_selection
from tqdm import tqdm
import gc




# generate data from csv file
class Build_dataset(Dataset):

    def __init__(self, csv, split, mode, transform=None):
        self.csv = csv.reset_index(drop=True)
        self.split = split
        self.mode = mode
        self.transform = transform

    def __len__(self):
        return self.csv.shape[0]

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        row = self.csv.iloc[index]

        image = cv2.imread(row.filepath)
        image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)

        if self.transform is not None:
            res = self.transform(image=image)
            image = res['image'].astype(np.float32)
        else:
            image = image.astype(np.float32)

        image = image.transpose(2, 0, 1)
        data = torch.tensor(image).float()

        if self.mode == 'test':
            return data
        else:
            return data, torch.tensor(self.csv.iloc[index].target).long()


# training epoch          
def train_epoch(model, loader, optimizer,loss_fn,device, scheduler,n_examples):

model = model.train()

losses = []
correct_predictions = 0

for inputs, labels in tqdm(loader):
    inputs = inputs.to(device)
    labels = labels.to(device)

    outputs = model(inputs)

    _, preds = torch.max(outputs, dim=1)
    loss = loss_fn(outputs, labels)
    
    
    correct_predictions += torch.sum(preds == labels)
    losses.append(loss.item())
    
    loss.backward()
    optimizer.step()
    optimizer.zero_grad()
# here you delete inputs and labels and then use gc.collect
    del inputs, labels
    gc.collect()


return correct_predictions.double() / n_examples, np.mean(losses)


# validation epoch 
def val_epoch(model, loader,loss_fn, device,n_examples):

model = model.eval()

losses = []
correct_predictions = 0

with torch.no_grad():
    for inputs, labels in tqdm(loader):
        inputs = inputs.to(device)
        labels = labels.to(device)
        outputs = model(inputs)
        _, preds = torch.max(outputs, dim=1)
        loss = loss_fn(outputs, labels)
        correct_predictions += torch.sum(preds == labels)
        losses.append(loss.item())
        # here you delete inputs and labels and then use gc.collect
        del inputs, labels
        gc.collect()
        

return correct_predictions.double() / n_examples, np.mean(losses)

def train(model,device, num_epochs):
# generate data
dataset_train = Build_dataset(df_train,  'train', 'train', transform=transforms_train)
dataset_valid = Build_dataset(df_valid, 'train', 'val', transform=transforms_val)

#load data 
train_loader = DataLoader(dataset_train, batch_size = 16,sampler=RandomSampler(dataset_train), num_workers=4)
valid_loader = DataLoader(dataset_valid, batch_size = 16,shuffle = True, num_workers= 4 )

dataset_train_size = len(dataset_train)

dataset_valid_size = len(dataset_valid)

optimizer = optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr = 3e-5)

model = model.to(device)

scheduler = lr_scheduler.ReduceLROnPlateau(optimizer, patience = 3,threshold = 0.001, mode = 'max')

loss_fn = nn.CrossEntropyLoss().to(device)

history = defaultdict(list)

best_accuracy = 0.0

for epoch in range(num_epochs):
    print(f'Epoch {epoch+1} / {num_epochs}')
    print ('-'*30)
    
    train_acc, train_loss = train_epoch(model, train_loader, optimizer, loss_fn, device, scheduler, dataset_train_size)
    print(f'Train loss {train_loss} accuracy {train_acc}')
    valid_acc, valid_loss = val_epoch(model, valid_loader, loss_fn, device,dataset_valid_size)
    print(f'Val   loss {valid_loss} accuracy {valid_acc}')
    print()
    
    history['train_acc'].append(train_acc)
    history['train_loss'].append(train_loss)
    history['val_acc'].append(valid_acc)
    history['val_loss'].append(valid_loss)
    
    if valid_acc > best_accuracy:
        torch.save(model.state_dict(), 'best_model_state.bin')
        best_accuracy = valid_acc
    
print('Best Accuracy: {best_accuracy}')

model.load_state_dict(torch.load('best_model_state.bin'))

return model, history


if __name__ == '__main__':
#competition data -2020
data_dir = "C:\\Users\\Aniruddh\\Documents\\kaggle\\jpeg_melanoma_2020"
#competition data - 2019
data_dir2 = "C:\\Users\\Aniruddh\\Documents\\kaggle\\jpeg_melanoma_2019"
# device
device = torch.device("cuda")

# augmenting images


image_size = 384
transforms_train = A.Compose([
    A.Transpose(p=0.5),
    A.VerticalFlip(p=0.5),
    A.HorizontalFlip(p=0.5),
    A.RandomBrightness(limit=0.2, p=0.75),
    A.RandomContrast(limit=0.2, p=0.75),
    A.OneOf([
        A.MedianBlur(blur_limit=5),
        A.GaussianBlur(blur_limit=5),
        A.GaussNoise(var_limit=(5.0, 30.0)),
    ], p=0.7),

    A.OneOf([
        A.OpticalDistortion(distort_limit=1.0),
        A.GridDistortion(num_steps=5, distort_limit=1.),
        A.ElasticTransform(alpha=3),
    ], p=0.7),

    A.CLAHE(clip_limit=4.0, p=0.7),
    A.HueSaturationValue(hue_shift_limit=10, sat_shift_limit=20, val_shift_limit=10, p=0.5),
    A.ShiftScaleRotate(shift_limit=0.1, scale_limit=0.1, rotate_limit=15, border_mode=0, p=0.85),
    A.Resize(image_size, image_size),
    A.Cutout(max_h_size=int(image_size * 0.375), max_w_size=int(image_size * 0.375), num_holes=1, p=0.7),    
    A.Normalize()
])

transforms_val = A.Compose([
    A.Resize(image_size, image_size),
    A.Normalize()
])
# create data
df_train = pd.read_csv("C:\\Users\\Aniruddh\\Documents\\kaggle\\jpeg_melanoma_2020\\train.csv")  #/kaggle/input/siim-isic-melanoma-classification/train.csv
df_train.head()

df_train['is_ext'] = 0
df_train['filepath'] = df_train['image_name'].apply(lambda x: os.path.join(data_dir, 'train', f'{x}.jpg'))

# dataset from 2020 data
df_train['diagnosis'] = df_train['diagnosis'].apply(lambda x: x.replace('seborrheic keratosis', 'BKL'))
df_train['diagnosis'] = df_train['diagnosis'].apply(lambda x: x.replace('lichenoid keratosis', 'BKL'))
df_train['diagnosis'] = df_train['diagnosis'].apply(lambda x: x.replace('solar lentigo', 'BKL'))
df_train['diagnosis'] = df_train['diagnosis'].apply(lambda x: x.replace('lentigo NOS', 'BKL'))
df_train['diagnosis'] = df_train['diagnosis'].apply(lambda x: x.replace('cafe-au-lait macule', 'unknown'))
df_train['diagnosis'] = df_train['diagnosis'].apply(lambda x: x.replace('atypical melanocytic proliferation', 'unknown'))

# dataset from 2019 data
df_train2 = pd.read_csv('/content/drive/My Drive/siim_melanoma images/train_2019.csv')
df_train2 = df_train2[df_train2['tfrecord'] >= 0].reset_index(drop=True)
#df_train2['fold'] = df_train2['tfrecord'] % 5
df_train2['is_ext'] = 1
df_train2['filepath'] = df_train2['image_name'].apply(lambda x: os.path.join(data_dir2, 'train', f'{x}.jpg'))

df_train2['diagnosis'] = df_train2['diagnosis'].apply(lambda x: x.replace('NV', 'nevus'))
df_train2['diagnosis'] = df_train2['diagnosis'].apply(lambda x: x.replace('MEL', 'melanoma'))

#concat both 2019 and 2020 data
df_train = pd.concat([df_train, df_train2]).reset_index(drop=True)

# shuffle data
df = df_train.sample(frac=1).reset_index(drop=True)

# creating 8 different target values
new_target = {d: idx for idx, d in enumerate(sorted(df.diagnosis.unique()))}
df['target'] = df['diagnosis'].map(new_target)
mel_idx = new_target['melanoma']

df = df[['filepath','diagnosis', 'target', 'is_ext']]

class_names = list(df['diagnosis'].unique())

# splitting train and validation data by 20%
df_valid = df[:11471]
df_train = df[11472:].reset_index()
df_train = df_train.drop(columns = ['index'])

# create model

def create_model(n_classes):
    model = models.resnet50(pretrained=True)

    n_features = model.fc.in_features
    model.fc = nn.Linear(n_features, n_classes)
    return model.to(device)

# model    
base_model = create_model(len(class_names)) 

# train model      
base_model, history = train(base_model, device, num_epochs = 15)
```

Code Objective

The purpose of the project is to classify skin cancer images by creating 8 different target variables from the given datasets (i.e the competition was about classifying benign and malignant images but I used the diagnosis column on the dataset as my target variable as the data was really skewed).  The model used is Resnet-50 from torchvision models.

These were the data used
skin images (this year competition): https://www.kaggle.com/cdeotte/jpeg-melanoma-384x384
skin images (last year competition): https://www.kaggle.com/cdeotte/jpeg-isic2019-384x384

I decided to create a Flask application out of this but, the CUDA memory was always causing a runtime error

```
RuntimeError: CUDA out of memory. Tried to allocate 144.00 MiB (GPU 0; 2.00 GiB total capacity; 1.21 GiB already allocated; 43.55 MiB free; 1.23 GiB reserved in total by PyTorch)
```

These are the details about my Nvidia GPU

```
Sun Sep 13 19:09:34 2020
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 451.67       Driver Version: 451.67       CUDA Version: 11.0     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name            TCC/WDDM | Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  GeForce 940MX      WDDM  | 00000000:01:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
| N/A   63C    P8    N/A /  N/A |     37MiB /  2048MiB |      0%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                                  |
|  GPU   GI   CI        PID   Type   Process name                  GPU Memory |
|        ID   ID                                                   Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|  No running processes found                                                 |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+

# more information about my GPU
==============NVSMI LOG==============

Timestamp                                 : Sun Sep 13 19:11:22 2020
Driver Version                            : 451.67
CUDA Version                              : 11.0

Attached GPUs                             : 1
GPU 00000000:01:00.0
Product Name                          : GeForce 940MX
Product Brand                         : GeForce
Display Mode                          : Disabled
Display Active                        : Disabled
Persistence Mode                      : N/A
Accounting Mode                       : Disabled
Accounting Mode Buffer Size           : 4000
Driver Model
    Current                           : WDDM
    Pending                           : WDDM
Serial Number                         : N/A
GPU UUID                              : GPU-9a8c69df-26f2-2a98-3712-ea22f6add038
Minor Number                          : N/A
VBIOS Version                         : 82.08.6D.00.8C
MultiGPU Board                        : No
Board ID                              : 0x100
GPU Part Number                       : N/A
Inforom Version
    Image Version                     : N/A
    OEM Object                        : N/A
    ECC Object                        : N/A
    Power Management Object           : N/A
GPU Operation Mode
    Current                           : N/A
    Pending                           : N/A
GPU Virtualization Mode
    Virtualization Mode               : None
    Host VGPU Mode                    : N/A
IBMNPU
    Relaxed Ordering Mode             : N/A
PCI
    Bus                               : 0x01
    Device                            : 0x00
    Domain                            : 0x0000
    Device Id                         : 0x134D10DE
    Bus Id                            : 00000000:01:00.0
    Sub System Id                     : 0x83F9103C
    GPU Link Info
        PCIe Generation
            Max                       : 3
            Current                   : 1
        Link Width
            Max                       : 4x
            Current                   : 4x
    Bridge Chip
        Type                          : N/A
        Firmware                      : N/A
    Replays Since Reset               : 0
    Replay Number Rollovers           : 0
    Tx Throughput                     : 0 KB/s
    Rx Throughput                     : 0 KB/s
Fan Speed                             : N/A
Performance State                     : P8
Clocks Throttle Reasons
    Idle                              : Not Active
    Applications Clocks Setting       : Not Active
    SW Power Cap                      : Not Active
    HW Slowdown                       : Not Active
        HW Thermal Slowdown           : N/A
        HW Power Brake Slowdown       : N/A
    Sync Boost                        : Not Active
    SW Thermal Slowdown               : Not Active
    Display Clock Setting             : Not Active
FB Memory Usage
    Total                             : 2048 MiB
    Used                              : 37 MiB
    Free                              : 2011 MiB
BAR1 Memory Usage
    Total                             : 256 MiB
    Used                              : 225 MiB
    Free                              : 31 MiB
Compute Mode                          : Default
Utilization
    Gpu                               : 0 %
    Memory                            : 0 %
    Encoder                           : N/A
    Decoder                           : N/A
Encoder Stats
    Active Sessions                   : 0
    Average FPS                       : 0
    Average Latency                   : 0
FBC Stats
    Active Sessions                   : 0
    Average FPS                       : 0
    Average Latency                   : 0
Ecc Mode
    Current                           : N/A
    Pending                           : N/A
ECC Errors
    Volatile
        Single Bit
            Device Memory             : N/A
            Register File             : N/A
            L1 Cache                  : N/A
            L2 Cache                  : N/A
            Texture Memory            : N/A
            Texture Shared            : N/A
            CBU                       : N/A
            Total                     : N/A
        Double Bit
            Device Memory             : N/A
            Register File             : N/A
            L1 Cache                  : N/A
            L2 Cache                  : N/A
            Texture Memory            : N/A
            Texture Shared            : N/A
            CBU                       : N/A
            Total                     : N/A
    Aggregate
        Single Bit
            Device Memory             : N/A
            Register File             : N/A
            L1 Cache                  : N/A
            L2 Cache                  : N/A
            Texture Memory            : N/A
            Texture Shared            : N/A
            CBU                       : N/A
            Total                     : N/A
        Double Bit
            Device Memory             : N/A
            Register File             : N/A
            L1 Cache                  : N/A
            L2 Cache                  : N/A
            Texture Memory            : N/A
            Texture Shared            : N/A
            CBU                       : N/A
            Total                     : N/A
Retired Pages
    Single Bit ECC                    : N/A
    Double Bit ECC                    : N/A
    Pending Page Blacklist            : N/A
Remapped Rows                         : N/A
Temperature
    GPU Current Temp                  : 60 C
    GPU Shutdown Temp                 : 99 C
    GPU Slowdown Temp                 : 94 C
    GPU Max Operating Temp            : 90 C
    Memory Current Temp               : N/A
    Memory Max Operating Temp         : N/A
Power Readings
    Power Management                  : N/A
    Power Draw                        : N/A
    Power Limit                       : N/A
    Default Power Limit               : N/A
    Enforced Power Limit              : N/A
    Min Power Limit                   : N/A
    Max Power Limit                   : N/A
Clocks
    Graphics                          : 405 MHz
    SM                                : 405 MHz
    Memory                            : 405 MHz
    Video                             : 396 MHz
Applications Clocks
    Graphics                          : 1006 MHz
    Memory                            : 1001 MHz
Default Applications Clocks
    Graphics                          : 1004 MHz
    Memory                            : 1001 MHz
Max Clocks
    Graphics                          : 1241 MHz
    SM                                : 1241 MHz
    Memory                            : 1001 MHz
    Video                             : 1216 MHz
Max Customer Boost Clocks
    Graphics                          : N/A
Clock Policy
    Auto Boost                        : N/A
    Auto Boost Default                : N/A
Processes                             : None
```

if I try running this on the CPU, the whole system freezes to the point where I have to manually restart the computer. Also if I try running the code with lower image resolution, lower batch sizes etc, each epoch takes around 12 hours to complete on a CPU which is definitely impractical.

Comment: The memory requirements of your model are probably too big to fit on your GPU or RAM.  Discussed more here - https://github.com/jolibrain/deepdetect/issues/84
Also consider trying out a smaller model, such as resnet-18, and, try training on Google Colab or Kaggle instead.

Comment: For a flask app try serving only the final model as an endpoint and run the inference on GPU. As mentioned in one of the answers the inference takes 1.3 GB only so should run on the GPU. If it still doesnt run please reduce the model size by changing to something like ResNet-18 or even smaller models like VGGnet

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ran your model on Kaggle with a `batch_size = 48` and attached a screenshot of the requirements. An epoch takes around 30-40 mins to complete. I would say you could easily train your model with the 30+ hrs Kaggle gives.

[image]

I also tested **inference** with `batch_size=1` and set `num_workers=0` in your dataloader, the GPU Usage is 1.3GB.

[image]

I would recommend you to train your model on Kaggle/Colab and download the weights onto your local machine. Later, you could run inference on your machine with  `batch size = 1`. Inference, usually happens faster.